# Second Jframe will not display

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I am using the GUI builder within netbeans 8.2 and I need a second frame to open when I click a button. I have researched how to do this and found multiple solutions but nothing has worked. the code is set up like this

```
private void playBTNActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        this.dispose();
        numOfPlayersGUI numPlayers = new numOfPlayersGUI();
        numPlayers.setVisible(true);
```

This should close the previous window where the button is and then open the new Frame. However It does not do that. I have tried messing around with where the new frame is located in terms of packages and how I've created the new frame and nothing has worked.

Another user suggested using this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml2b6XBunMI, and I followed It to the T and still nothing.

NumOfPlayersGUI -

```
public NumOfPlayersGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Pick how many CPU players you");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("would like to play with");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(126, 126, 126)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                .addContainerGap(65, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(287, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumOfPlayersGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumOfPlayersGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumOfPlayersGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumOfPlayersGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NumOfPlayersGUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration
```

Comment: Please show us the class `numOfPlayersGUI`. And keep in mind classes should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Whoops i forgot a new frame is a new class. I fixed that error. The code for the NumOfPlayersGUI is now in the main question. (all It is is the generated code from a jframe form plus a couple labels)